# How to install Windows Phone app for beta testing without purchasing a certificate

Tags: testing, windows-phone, beta

I have a Windows Phone individual developer account and need to do a beta testing internally. I used Appaloosa and HockeyApp for this purpose. But, when I try to download the app and install it on my Windows Phone, it shows a message "Can't install company app" on both Appaloosa and HockeyApp.

I heard that one needs to have a Symantec certificate and an .aetx file in order to install Windows Phone app which costs $299.00.

I need to know if there is any other option so that I can install my developed app freely on some Windows Phone devices which are intended for testing. I might need to email my .xap file to the testers and let them download and install for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can install your developed app on some Windows Phone devices from Windows Store. If you have development account, you can publish your app with limited access. You will get link on your app. Your app will access only for people, who have this link. Another people will not find your app in Windows Store.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My doubt is, can I publish my app in Windows Store freely without purchasing a certificate for testing purpose? I have  an individual developer account.